# Add lists with unequal lengths together to create a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart using raw data coming from a MySQL server. The result coming back from one query is:

```
{{SQLDateTime[{2011, 7, 23, 13, 0, 0.}], 74}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 8, 11, 15, 35, 54.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 8, 18, 9, 28, 14.}], 49}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 8, 24, 21, 45, 29.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 8, 31, 10, 0, 18.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 9, 8, 10, 6, 45.}], 5}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 9, 14, 9, 35, 40.}], 10}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 9, 15, 6, 27, 12.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 9, 21, 9, 47, 26.}], 6}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 9, 29, 10, 5, 2.}], 3}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 10, 6, 9, 34, 26.}], 3}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 10, 24, 9, 31, 42.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 10, 27, 9, 52, 7.}], 2}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 11, 25, 10, 53, 27.}], 2}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 12, 1, 11, 0, 21.}], 3}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 12, 6, 10, 49, 42.}], 3}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2011, 12, 8, 14, 38, 54.}], 1}, 
 {SQLDateTime[{2012, 3, 27, 8, 10, 31.}], 1}}
```

I'm going to get ten similar sets of results. The difference will be that they don't contain all of the same dates. I need to create a matrix like so:

The first row is a list of dates. Each result set will contain different dates and some will be the same and some not, think of this first row as a list of unique dates pooled together from all result sets. Should be ordered chronologically.

Row number two lists the correponding values in each column. Look at my example result set above. Each date has a value corresponding to it. All of these values make up a row, with each element under its corresponding date. There will be dates in the first row for which there are no corresponding values in this particular result set, these elements should be zero.

There will be one row for each result set plus the top row consisting of dates.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are the dates returned in each query guaranteed to be unique? If not, how would you handle multiple values for the same date?

Comment: I rewrote my question, hopefully it is now more understandable. The dates are unique in each result set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a free kernel to try your question on, so here's a smaller generalized approach that I could construct in my head. In the end, I'll mention how you can adapt it to yours.

First, consider a non-rectangular list similar to yours:

```
list = {{{1, a}, {2, b}}, 
        {{3, a}, {2, c}, {4, f}}, 
        {{3, b}, {6, f}, {4, c}, {5, e}}};
```

The output expected here is a 3x6 matrix with each column corresponding to the unique elements and each row having the corresponding element or zero. Obtaining the unique elements and constructing a larger matrix, as the following, we get:

```
With[{un = Union@Flatten@list[[All, All, 1]]},
    (un /. Rule@@@#&)/@list /. _Integer -> 0
]

(* Out[1] = {{a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
             {0, c, a, f, 0, 0}, 
             {0, 0, b, c, e, f}} 
*)
```

which, I believe, is what you want. If you want the first row to be the list of unique elements, simply join `un` with the rest as:

```
With[{un = Union@Flatten@list[[All, All, 1]]},
    {un} ~Join~ ((un /. Rule@@@#&)/@list /. _Integer -> 0)
]

(* Out[2]= {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
            {a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {0, c, a, f, 0, 0}, 
            {0, 0, b, c, e, f}} 
*)
```

Now the only change that's required for this to work on your data is to use `_SQLDateTime` instead of `_Integer` in the `With` construct above.

Comment: Please confirm if this works and gives you the result. Also, `list` above is the equivalent of the collected output from your 10 different queries.

Comment: This works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This is based on `SparseArray`, like [rcollyer's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4138/531), but it's a one-liner since everything can by done by `Apply`ing `Rule` at the proper level and then using `PadRight` to turn a ragged array into a rectangular one. Let

```
list = {{{1, a}, {2, b}}, 
        {{3, a}, {2, c}, {4, f}}, 
        {{3, b}, {6, f}, {4, c}, {5, e}}};
```

Then:

```
PadRight[Normal /@ SparseArray /@ (Apply[Rule, list, {2}])]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, c, a, f, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, b, c, e, f}}
> ```

**EDIT** to add: Of course, the real trick is getting the first row right, like @rcollyer points out in the comments below. It's possible to extend this solution in a manner similar to the one in [R.M.'s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4117/531), but I'm not sure how much that wins you:

```
Pillsy`Rectangularize[lists : {___List}] := 
 With[{columns = Union@Cases[lists, {n_, _} :> n, {2}]},
  Prepend[
   PadRight[Normal /@ SparseArray /@
      (lists /. 
        MapThread[{#1, v_} :> (#2 -> v) &, {columns, 
           Range@Length@columns}])],
   columns]]
```

I tested the function with the following:

```
namedList = list /. Thread[Range[6] -> CharacterRange["A", "F"]]
```

> ```
> {{{"A", a}, {"B", b}}, 
>  {{"C", a}, {"B", c}, {"D", f}}, 
>  {{"C", b}, {"F", f}, {"D", c}, {"E", e}}}
> ```

```
Pillsy`Rectangularize[namedList]
```

> ```
> {{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}, 
>  {a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, c, a, f, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, b, c, e, f}}
> ```

I did come up with a totally different solution based on `Ordering` and `DeleteDuplicates` which I kind of like:

```
Pillsy`AnotherRectangularize[lists_] :=
 With[{columns = Union @@ lists[[All, All, 1]]},
  Prepend[
   Part[PadRight[#[[All, -1]], Length@columns],
      Ordering@DeleteDuplicates[#[[All, 1]]~Join~columns]] & /@ lists,
   columns]]
```

Much belated **EDIT**, using `Association` functionality:

```
ClearAll[Pillsy`Rectangularize];
Pillsy`Rectangularize[lists : {{{_, _} ...} ..}] :=
 Transpose@KeyValueMap[Prepend[#2, #1] &]@
  KeySort@Merge[
    KeyUnion[Map[Transpose /* Apply[AssociationThread], lists], 0 &],
    Identity]
```

Comment: Where's the first row which for the OP's dataset would be the dates?

Comment: I love how getting the first row correct adds so much additional complexity to the solution. Also, `Normal` can be applied using postfix notation as it will automatically "normalize" to all depths. +1, btw.

Comment: Come to think of it, the first row can be extracted and properly ordered using `Union@Flatten@list[[All, All, 1]]` which then can be prepended or joined to the matrix.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative method based upon [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html) and [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html).

```
Reap[
 MapIndexed[
  Sow[#2[[1]] -> #1[[2]], First@#1] &, 
  list, {2}  (* <-- Note level specifier *)
 ], _, 
 Flatten@{#1, Normal@SparseArray[#2, Length@list]} &][[2]] // 
SortBy[#, First] & // Transpose
```

If you are not familiar with these two functions, `Sow` tags each item you indicate and `Reap` organizes the items by each tag. Among the advantages of `Reap` and `Sow` over [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GatherBy.html) is the ability to simultaneously transform each item while tagging it with one of its original properties. Here I take advantage of this by using `MapIndexed` to tag each datum with its first element (second parameter in `Sow`) while associating the second element of the datum with the index of its data set. (This is done by using the `{2}` as the level specifier.) For example,

```
MapIndexed[#2[[1]]->#1[[2]], list, {2}]
```

with

```
list = {
        {{1, a}, {2, b}}, 
        {{3, a}, {2, c}, {4, f}}, 
        {{3, b}, {6, f}, {4, c}, {5, e}}
       };
```

gives

> ```
> {{1 -> a, 1 -> b}, 
>  {2 -> a, 2 -> c, 2 -> f}, 
>  {3 -> b, 3 -> f, 3 -> c, 3 -> e}}
> ```

By creating the association with the data set index, we are marking which row it will end up in after `Reap` collects them. `Reap` allows us to specify an additional transformation taking 2 parameters the tag and a list of items with that tag as its third argument. For example,

```
Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2[[1]] -> #1[[-1]], First@#1] &, list, {2}], 
 _, Rule][[2]]
```

using `list` from above gives

> ```
> {1 -> {1 -> a}, 
>  2 -> {1 -> b, 2 -> c}, 
>  3 -> {2 -> a, 3 -> b}, 
>  4 -> {2 -> f, 3 -> c}, 
>  6 -> {3 -> f}, 5 -> {3 -> e}}
> ```

As you can see, this has collected the data according to the first element of each datum while retaining information about which dataset it belongs to.

Since the tagged data has the form, `{_Integer -> value ..}`, we can use [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SparseArray.html) to generate each row while automatically filling in the empty spaces with `0`. This is what I do with

```
Flatten@{#1, Normal@SparseArray[#2, Length@list]} &
```

as the third parameter.

Then, I just `SortBy` the `First` element of each sub-list, and `Transpose` it into its final form

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
>  {a, b, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, c, a, f, 0, 0}, 
>  {0, 0, b, c, e, f}}
> ```

---

As to the specific dataset involving `SQLDateTime`, it appears that `SQLDateTime` contains a full date-time stamp. It is unlikely that any two datum will have the same date-time stamp, so if you want to gather within a full day only, change

```
Sow[#2[[1]] -> #1[[2]], First@#1] &
```

to

```
Sow[#2[[1]] -> #1[[2]], { #1[[1, ;;3]] } ] &
```

where `#1[[1, ;;3]]` only extracts what appears to be the date part of `SQLDateTime`. This could be extended to include hours or even minutes by changing `;;3` to `;;4` or `;;5`, respectively.  Note, I wrapped the tag in an extra set of braces so that the entire date is considered a tag, and not a collection of individual tags.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. And you were right about only wanting to compare full days :)